# Why when I compare the int values of an RDDpipeline i get both int and none values?

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd, nonetype

I have a csv file that contains fields with the values `1` and `0`. Using pyspark I want to capture only those values with `1` in a specific field. When I convert the fields I transform them to `int`. When I use an `if` statement to check if the value is `1`, it returns me a lot of `None` and some `1`. Why do I have this problem? I am 100% sure that my csv file contains only the values `1` and `0`?

```
def vehA(line):
  fields = line.split(",")
  ddsA = int(fields[28]) 
  ddsB = int(fields[52]) 

  if ddsA == 1:
     return ddsA

rdd = lines.map(vehA)
rdd.collect()
```

Output:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
None
None
None
None
1
1
1
1
1
1
None
None
...
```

I even tried this and I still get the same output:

```
    if ddsA is not None:
        if ddsA == 1 and ddsA is not None:
          return ddsA
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method `vehA` returns `None` when `ddsA` is not equal to `1` as you are not returning anything in case of `else` python implicitly returns `None`.

In order to capture only `ddsA` with one you could use filter instead of map.